# PHP Date validation English to American format

Tags: php, date, time

I've come across many date based questions and solutions, but nothing that is quite what I'm used to.

I'm working on a site for the USA market, therefore the dates are commonly m/d/Y. However the English and other English speaking countries will also use it and they are likely to want to put d/m/Y.

It seems PHP Date can understand the former, but not the latter. If I could guarantee the use of d/m/Y and not either it would be simple.

Has anyone come across a solution that can detect the type of date and make the necessary correction for processing?

Comment: Unless you know, where to use `d/m/y` and `m/d/y` its impossible to detect the right date. for example: 1/2/2012 is this January 2,2012 or February 1,2012? both are acceptable, considering your 2 formats, but w/c is the right date?

Answer (score 0):

`strftime()` and other date-time functions are locale dependent. Use `setlocale()` to pre-define the formats you want php to use. E.g.:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'en_UK');
```